# Two Possible Latin Puns?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

The first is a very endearing quote by CS Lewis, from an apology note when he forgot to meet a friend for lunch (taken from A Severe Mercy):

> *Porcus sum*, I am a pig, *porcissimus*, the piggest of pigs. I looked at my diary at about 3 o’clock on Sat. afternoon and found to my horror that I had failed a tryst with you at 12. Please forgive a nit-wit. Will you prove your charity by meeting me at the Eastgate 12 o’clock next Saturday? Even I seldom make exactly the same howler twice! I really am very sorry; I had been much looking forward to it. C.S.L.

*Porcus sum* is "I am a piglet", but I don't know what *porcissimus* is, though I suspect it is a pun in Latin.

The second is from G.K. Chesterton in The Philosophy of Islands:

> “Did you or did you not as a child try to step on every alternate paving-stone ? Was that artificial and a superstition? Did priests come in the dead of night and mark out by secret signs the stones on which you are allowed to tread? ... Has the Church issued a bill “Quisquam non pavemente?”

Another source says that the above Latin can be translated as "Whatsoever is not pavement", but also, "Whatsoever does not nourish the mind." Is this a correct or near-correct interpretation?

Comment: Doesn't Lewis explain? ... *porcissimus*, the **piggest of pigs**.

Comment: Weather Vane, I think you are correct; it seems the -imus ending gives it a superlative form. Thank you! I moved the other question to the latin stack exchange.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a migrated question from English Stack, but it was restated here: [Possible Latin Pun?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15298/possible-latin-pun)

Comment: I agree with @C.M.Weimer: One half of the question was already posted here. The other one can be asked separately, but that is by far simplest to do by asking a separate question. I'm not sure if the migration is reversed due to this closure.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta The comments weren't made from Latin.SE, but English.SE. I guess a moderator moved it here instead of just closing it.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Yeah, at least the moderator interface shows that it was migrated from English. I just should have been closed instead of migrated, especially because of the comment of having the other part already here.